# upgrading from PHP 5.2.17 to 5.2.6 on Windows Server 2008 IIS 7

Tags: php, windows

I've been searching on this matter but didn't seem to find the right guide or answer.
I run Windows Server 2008 IIS 7. (I'm not expert in this yet)

First of all, exact file...there are many files so I am not sure if 
php-5.2.6-nts-Win32 is right one for me.

http://kr2.php.net/releases/
Download: PHP 5.2.6 (tar.bz2) PHP 5.2.6 (tar.gz) PHP 5.2.6 zip package PHP 5.2.6 installer PECL 5.2.6 Win32 binaries PHP 5.2.6 Win32 Debug Pack PHP 5.2.6 Non-thread-safe zip package PHP 5.2.6 Non-thread-safe installer PHP 5.2.6 Win32 Debug Pack PECL 5.2.6 Non-thread-safe Win32 binaries

If I know exact file to download.
After that, how should I proceed the upgrade?

I tried overwritting on existing folder that is running PHP 5.2.17...somehow Joomla site seemed work fine except some other sites that used PEAR or other ext...
I guess it's not the right way...

I would be really grateful if you could help me with successfully upgrading PHP for Joomla program that I want to use...

Thank you!!

PS. What is "x86 Non Thread Safe" "win32 binary" ?

Comment: From 5.2.17 to 5.2.6? It's not *upgrading*, it is *downgrading*...

Comment: @binaryLV I'm not familiar with PHP versioning, please explain how going from 5.2.17 to 5.2.6 is downgrading.. the increase would suggest an upgrade..?

Comment: @Jiyoung, version numbers are not decimals (neither for PHP nor for other software), i.e., 5.2.6 is not the same as 5.2.60 or 5.2.6000. As for PHP, 5.2.6 was released on 01-May-2008 (you can see this in the link you already gave), 5.2.17 was released on 06-Jan-2011 (info from http://www.php.net/ startpage).

Answer (score 2):

First i must "upgrading" to 5.2.6 ? Isn't it downgrading to it ?

If it's a mistake and you mean 5.3.6 not 5.2.6 than:

Just the other day i finished doing the same thing. PHP 5.2.17 to 5.3.6.
On the IIS 7(7.5) install this (PHP Manager for IIS) the http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/ .

Doing this will give you the power to have both 5.2.17 and 5.3.6 on the same machine but on different folders. eg:

```
D:\php-5.2.17\
D:\php-5.3.6\
```

with the php.ini files in each directory.

After you install the IIS plugin you now have this in your server configuration:

[image: http://download.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=phpmanager&DownloadId=177513]

Now you can quickly and easy change the current SITE PHP version and make changes to the INI file. Add or remove extension etc.

Comment: THANK YOU!! THIS IS GREAT SOLUTION!!! I'll try that out! Can't express much!! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! :)

Comment: I also need to do the same thing, can you please tell it would'nt create any problem bcz many websites are runnig on server.